# Value from Grails controller breaking javascript in gsp

Tags: javascript, xml, string, grails, jstree

I am passing XML string from grails controller to gsp and need to use it in the javascript function for showing treeview using jstree.

My controller code is

```
    render(view: "list",model: [dataXML: callXML.getXmlString()])
```

The javascript function in gsp code is

```
    function callXML(){
            var xmlStr = "${dataXML}";
            _uimTree = new UIMTreeProcessor(parseXml(), jQuery("#jstree"));
            _uimTree.doProcess();
    }

    function parseXML(){
            if (window.DOMParser) {
                return new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
            }else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
                var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = "false";
                xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
                return xmlDoc;
            }else{
                return jQuery(xmlStr);
            }
    }
```

Controller:

```
def showModel = { 
    CallXML callXML = new CallXML(); 
    callXML.setXmlString(); 
    def productFlowModels = new XmlParser().parseText(callXML.getXmlString()); 
    println callXML.getXmlString(); 
    render(view: "list",model: [dataXML: callXML.getXmlString() as String]) 
}
```

As soon as the ${dataXML} comes in function it breaks the code. I tried without quotes, still same problem.
What is that I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you getting ?

Comment: I do not get any error, I just get nothing when I do `alert(xmlStr);`

Answer (score 1):

If you have xml string, you should be able to access it from your controller like this:

Controller:

```
def list(Integer max) {
        def xmlString = """<langs type="current">
                             <language>Java</language>
                             <language>Groovy</language>
                             <language>JavaScript</language>
                           </langs>"""

        def xml = new XmlParser().parseText( xmlString )
        render (view:'list',model: [dataXML:xml ])
    }
```

GSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function my(){
            var str = "${dataXML.encodeAsHTML()}"
            alert (str)
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>
        ${dataXML.encodeAsHTML()}
    </p>
           <script>
               my()
           </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for sample code. I am getting null for 

`var str = "${dataXML.encodeAsHTML()}"
            alert (str)`

Comment: can you post your controller action? Are you sure dataXML has data in your controller?

Comment: Thanks @Alidad, yes I am able to print in the console dataXML
The controller action is ***********                                    
`def showModel = {
        CallXML callXML = new CallXML();
        callXML.setXmlString();

        def productFlowModels = new XmlParser().parseText(callXML.getXmlString());
        println callXML.getXmlString();
        def  productFlowModel =    productFlowModels.productFlowModel[0]
        println productFlowModel.@uid
        assert productFlowModel.@uid == params.uid

        render(view: "list",model: [dataXML: callXML.getXmlString() as String])
    }`

Comment: Look at my controller, parse your xml string then return it.

Comment: I did exactly same, but after inspecting element I found error  `var str = "&lt;langs type=&quot;current&quot;&gt;
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
                             &lt;language&gt;Java&lt;/language&gt;
                             &lt;language&gt;Groovy&lt;/language&gt;
                             &lt;language&gt;JavaScript&lt;/language&gt;
                           &lt;/langs&gt;";
                alert(xmlStr);`

Comment: But it works fine in HTML and shows in <p> tag `Java Groovy JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

in your model, use

```
render(view: "list",model: [dataXML: JsonOutput.toJson(callXML.getXmlString())])
```

You need to properly encode strings as javascript strings if you are going to output them in a javascript context.

Comment: Thanks I tried but I get error as when I add `import groovy.json.JsonOutput`

Comment: Is this due to IDE IntelliJ setting or something?

Comment: no idea, the doc says its correct : http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonOutput.html

Comment: I got why `JsonOutput` doesn't work, it is due to lower version of Grails I am using